# Pass a bash variable to python script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I have [this python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38822941/3393576):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def getPermutation(s, prefix=''):
        if len(s) == 0:
                print prefix
        for i in range(len(s)):
                getPermutation(s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)],prefix+s[i] )



getPermutation('abcd','')
```

However, I want to be able to call this script using a variable for "abcd" so I can insert any combination of letters instead of "abcd"  like "efgh" for example.

Normally, I can use a `$@` or `$1` instead of `abcd` on the last line in a bash script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def getPermutation(s, prefix=''):
        if len(s) == 0:
                print prefix
        for i in range(len(s)):
                getPermutation(s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)],prefix+s[i] )



getPermutation("$1",'')
```

But when I run the script using something like `./scriptname.py efgh` I get:

```
$1
1$
```

instead of the permutations for "efgh".

Comment: [Python - Command Line Arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Comment: Duplicate on Stack Overflow: [How do I access command line arguments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033723/4518341)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The python equivalent of the shell's positional parameter array `$1`, `$2` etc. is `sys.argv`

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def getPermutation(s, prefix=''):
        if len(s) == 0:
                print prefix
        for i in range(len(s)):
                getPermutation(s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)],prefix+s[i] )



getPermutation(sys.argv[1],'')
```

then

```
$ ./foo.py abcd
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
cbda
cdab
cdba
dabc
dacb
dbac
dbca
dcab
dcba
```

Answer (score 7):

Lots of ways to parameterize python. positional args, env variables, and named args.
Env variables:

import os and use the getenv like:

```
fw_main_width  =os.getenv('FW_MAIN_WIDTH',  fw_main_width)
```

Where the second parameter is the default for the env variable not being set.

Positional args:

Use the sys.argc, sys.argv[n] after you import sys.

Named parameters:

Or for named parameters,(what you asked)

```
 import argparse
```

then describe the possible parameters:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Project", fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument("-V", "--version", help="show program version", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-W", "--width", help="set main screen width")  
read arguments from the command line  

args = parser.parse_args()
```

and use them as args.width  etc.

Comment: I didn't really understand this at first but this really helps explain the accepted answer and now it makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured out a workaround while I was writing the question but I felt that this would useful to other users so here it is.

For python (python2), we can use `raw_input()` instead of `$1` but it works a bit differently. Instead of entering the input after the script name in bash, you are prompted to input the value *after* you run the script.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def getPermutation(s, prefix=''):
        if len(s) == 0:
                print prefix
        for i in range(len(s)):
                getPermutation(s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)],prefix+s[i] )



getPermutation(raw_input("enter characters: "),'')
```

Running the script will prompt the user to "enter characters:". After the user enters the characters and then presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the permutations will print in the terminal.

[Here is the source which also explains how to do this for python3.](https://stackabuse.com/getting-user-input-in-python/)

Comment: This might 'work' for you, but you're not actually answering your own question, which is about passing a variable ;)

Comment: @djsmiley2k Yes, it's a workaround. That's why I accepted the other answer as the solution.

Comment: *Meanwhile Python 2 gets deprecated*

Comment: @Kulfy I used python2 because it is the system default for `python` on 18.04. I've had to use python3 for maths in the past because python2 likes to round the numbers. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools, argparse

def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-l', '--letters', dest='letters',  type=str, help='Letters to iterate over')
        options = parser.parse_args()


        a = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(options.letters)]
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

On the command line: FileName.py -l abcd